# Changing CSS value with Shell Script - Unix

Tags: html, css, shell, unix

Is it possible to change an element value in CSS via sh script in unix? If so how would this been done?

Aim: I have an html site with multiple div boxes that are coloured based on alarming state, eg.. red, yellow, green.

I have an auto refresh for the HTML site, so all i want to do is to be able to add a line to my current sh scripts to change the css based on results to show the alarming state.

I was thinking using 'sed' as per below, but it needs to be element specific and not just change all reds to blues so to speak.

```
cat test.css | sed -e 's/RED/BLUE/' > test.css
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Will editing the .css file using literal strings be enough for you? or are you planning on something dynamic? I can't understand the question. there has to be a less painful way to do what you need.

Comment: @Rodik I have added more information to clarify, Hopefully that helps.

Comment: what stops you from using javascript+ajax to get the info, and coloring the divs dynamically, without refreshing the page?

Comment: @Rodik I already have scripts setup for alarming, so I would like to keep it as simple as possible as it is running on production servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your element an id and add a line in the CSS for that id. Then, using sed, change that line.

Say in the HTML the element looks like

```
<element id="box123" ... / >
```

and in the CSS this would get its color:

```
#box123 { color: #000000; }
```

then you change the color via changing the CSS using sed:

```
$ sed -i 's/^#box123 { color: #000000; }/^#box123 { color: #0000ff; }/g' cssfile
```

or shorter but with advanced sed methods:

```
$ sed -i 's/^#box123\(.*\)#000000/^#box123\1#0000ff/g' cssfile
```

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: I have added it to the answer above.